# Integrating square of Fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-series

This is in an Electrical Engineering context, where I'm finding power over a period as: $P =\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} \frac{v(t)^2}{R} dt$, for some arbitrary time $T$ and some constant $R$.

I'm having trouble integrating for $P$ given $v(t)$ as the Fourier series of a square wave:
$$v(t) = \frac{4V}{π}•(sin(ωt) + \frac{1}{3}sin(3ωt)+\frac{1}{5}sin(5ωt) ...)$$
for some constant $ω$ and $V$.

My biggest issue is how to integrate the series of $sin$ functions that's also squared.

Comment: integrating $\sin(at) \sin(bt)$ is not difficult as $\sin(t) = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2}$

Comment: @reuns yes, but I ran into trouble when I had to integrate a square of a (converging) infinite sum of sines. They sum to V, as I have somehow failed to detect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square wave of unit amplitude has the [Fourier series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html)
$$v(t)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(2n+1)t}{T}\right)$$
so your function $v$ is a square wave of amplitude $V$ and period $T$. This is easy to integrate:
$$P=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\frac{v(t)^2}{R}dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\frac{V^2}{R}dt=\frac{V^2}{RT}\cdot T=\frac{V^2}{R}.$$

Comment: Dear lord I see the idiocy in my question...v(t) directly sums to V, since it's a square wave.